# How can I set up a code review process to my remote peers before checking in to TFS?

Tags: eclipse, tfs, tfs-code-review

My development environment is set up behind a corporate proxy through remote VMs. We uses Visual Studio as the main platform for our code developement , so we had no issue with code review process as Team Foundation Server have this feature.

However recently, we switch to eclipse while still maintaining the projects in TFS. Eclipse have TFS plugin which is good as we can continue on from our previous track without much effort. The only thing missing is the code review.

So, is there anyone who worked using TFS and eclipse in offline mode behind a corporate proxy, have an alternative way to do code review just like visual studio + TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on which version control system your team  are using.

### If you are using GIT as source control.

For now, the Team Foundation Server plug-in for Eclipse (Team Explorer Everywhere) supports [pull requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/code/git/pull-requests) to review code and collaborate with members of your team.

> Collaborate
>   *Work and code together*
>
> Use pull requests to review code and collaborate with members of your
>   team. Triage and track comments at each stage of the work to ensure no
>   feedback gets lost. Finally, configure merge, build, and review
>   policies for your Git branches and stay up-to-date with alerts.
>
> Source: [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx)

### If you are using TFVC as source control.

There is no this function in the plug-in directly. You may need to use 3-party code-review plugins to achieve it. Such as [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/), [Checkstyle Plug-in](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/checkstyle-plug)...

If you want to enforce Code review before any checkin in TFS server. You may need to use [check-in policies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg475890(v=vs.100).aspx) which can evaluate whether the pending changes meet the validation requirements before they can be checked in to the server. So, if the code review through Sonar can be called programmatically, then you can build a **custom check-in policy** that calls Sonar inside the Evaluate method.